# Find DIV width when multiple DIVs share the same ID

Tags: javascript, html, width

I have searched all day and can´t find an answer to my problem.

I have the folowing DIV setup:

```
<div id="MainDiv1">
    <div id="Galery1">
        <div id="Image" style="width:100px;"></div>
        <div id="Image" style="width:100px;"></div>
        <div id="Image" style="width:100px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="MainDiv2">
    <div id="Galery2">
        <div id="Image" style="width:80px;"></div>
        <div id="Image" style="width:80px;"></div>
        <div id="Image" style="width:80px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need is, with Javascript, to set a variable with the Width of any of the "Image" DIV, but only the ones in the "Galery1".
Since they all have the same width any of them will work.

I have tryed:

```
DIVwidth = document.getElementById("Image");
```

But this always gives me back 80px, that are from the "Galery2" DIV.
I assume I have to give a Path somehow to limit the search into the "Galery1" or "MainDiv1" DIVs.

I can not give unique names to the DIVs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID. You should use something like `class` instead.

Comment: @Lukas: That should be the answer

Comment: IDs in any area of computing should always be used to **uniquely** identify a *thing*. This is your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs should be unique. I.E. you should not have more than one `id="Image"`

To select the first div in `Gallery2` try this:

```
document.getElementById( 'Gallery2' ).getElementsByTagName( 'div' )[0]; // <-- '0' gets first item from array
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for.
Just tested it and it works great.
I will follow all the previous comments about not using the same ID for multiple DIVs, and will do the proper changes in my code.
Thanks you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost it will help you to understand the difference between ids and classes: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

That in mind, you should change all of your Image ID'd elements to Image Classed elements:

```
<div id="MainDiv1">
    <div id="Galery1">
        <div class="Image" style="width:100px;"></div>
        <div class="Image" style="width:100px;"></div>
        <div class="Image" style="width:100px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="MainDiv2">
    <div id="Galery2">
        <div class="Image" style="width:80px;"></div>
        <div class="Image" style="width:80px;"></div>
        <div class="Image" style="width:80px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Selecting an image from Gallery 1 becomes simply:

`document.getElementById("Galery1").getElementsByClassName('Image')[0]`

`document.getElementById("Galery1").getElementsByClassName('Image')` will return an array of matched elements (elements with a class of "Image" nested under the element with the ID "Galery1") and `[0]` selects the first index of the returned array.

---

Alternatively you can simply select the first Image on the page by doing: `document.getElementsByClassName('Image')`